# How do I override a written function when a certain module is imported?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a placeholder Point and Rectangle function, but I want to use Zelle's graphics module's ones if they're present

```
class Pt:
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if ('graphics' in sys.modules):
            return graphics.Point(x, y)
class R:
    def __init__(self, tLPoint, w, h):
        self.P1 = tLPoint
        self.P2 = Pt(tLPoint.x + w, tLPoint.y + h)
        self.x = tLPoint.x
        self.y = tLPoint.y
        if ('graphics' in sys.modules):
            return graphics.Rectangle(P1, P2)
```

That's the code I've got so far, but `__init__` gets annoyed when you return something through it.

What I want to do is to return the Zelle's graphics version if it exists, instead of the custom one.

I'm not entirely sure what to do with this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `__init__` isn't supposed to return anything... It's purely to initialise the object after it has been constructed so that you can then use the object...

Comment: isn't subclassing what you want to do here? inherit from `graphics.Point` or something?

Comment: @JonClements I know. I wasn't sure what to do, so I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist not entirely sure what you mean by that

Comment: @CalebHoward so if `graphics` is imported - you want to use their Point and Rectangle or you want to use your own implementations?

Comment: Seems simplest to just make `graphics` a dependency of the project

Comment: @JonClements I want to use theirs.

Comment: Then just use them.... `class Pt(graphics.Point):`... and override anything you need if you do need to do that or just use them directly?

Comment: @JonClements I guess, but what I want to do with the entire project won't always need graphics, and having it in (in those cases) would be mostly pointless

Comment: What's wrong with having it and not using it as opposed to all the logic hoops you're lending yourself towards by this approach?

Comment: If you're writing your own module that should be fallen back on if `graphics` isn't present that's one thing. However, you say you want to use theirs, which means you need it installed for when you do... so that's something different...

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Something to fall back on if graphics is not present. I only want to use it if it's present

Comment: @CalebHoward okay... seems an odd approach though. You're going to write your own version of `graphics` for when it's not there... so now you've got effectively two modules/classes that are meant to do the same thing... Just makes more sense to me to ensure that `graphics` is required instead of bundling your own copy for when it's not present... seems like a maintenance nightmare in terms of compatibility, user expectations and debugging later on... I can't help but feel you're over complicating this and doing a lot of work for no real gain... just make `graphics` a dependency and you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate an instance of a specific class, you can't make the constructor suddenly return an instance of a completely different class.  And aside from not working, it would also be incredibly confusing.  Perhaps something like this would suit you:

```
def create_point(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'graphics' in sys.modules:
        return graphics.Point(*args, **kwargs)
    return Pt(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you just use `create_point(x, y)` whenever you need an instance.

Comment: If going this route I would probably not depend on the developer having remembered to import graphics somewhere in that module and instead `try: import graphics; return graphics.Point(...) except ImportError: return Pt(...)` or something like that... Could end up with a load of factory functions though unless you make a general create factory function or proxy class of some sort...

Answer (score 2):

Since classes are objects in Python, you could assign the class you want to a variable, at module level.

```
if 'graphics' in sys.modules:
    Point = graphics.Point
    Rectangle = graphics.Rectangle
else
    Point = Pt
    Rectangle = R
```

Comment: The only problem is that the arguments are different between the two Rectangles (for the Points, it's not an issue)

Comment: @CalebHoward Then it seems like they use different interfaces and cannot be used interchangeably. You could use a Factory pattern as jih shown in their answer, given that they share the same interface *after* they've been created.

Comment: @CalebHoward Remember that you can have problems using that pattern though. If someone programs against the interface for Zelle's Rectangle class, and then they change to another computer where it's not available, then they'll have to manually change all places where a Rectangle object is created, because the call to the constructor would require an additional argument.